# Change zoom value in leaflet Tile Layer URL?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a map server with Leaflet, and my tiles url is `www.examplemyserver.com/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`
But my tiles zoom is Upside down with leaflet tiles zoom .
For example when zoom is 1  I want zoom set 21  and when zoom is 2 but set zoom 20  in string my tiles url.

```
 leafletzoom   I want set myserverzoom
     1              21
     2              20
     3              19
     .              .
     .              .
     .              .
     20             2
     21             1
```

I tried this but not work :

```
var ZoomDict={1:21,2:20,3:19,4:18,5:17,6:16,7:15,8:14,9:13,10:12,11:11,12:10,13:9,14:8,15:7,16:6,17:5,18:4,19:3,20:2,21:1};

mp=L.tileLayer('http://www.examplemyserver.com/'+"{ZoomDict['{z}']}"+'/{x}/{y}.jpg').addto(map)// out put: URL for tiles is :  http://www.examplemyserver.com/{ZoomDict['{7}']}/45/245.jpg'  
or
mp=L.tileLayer('http://www.examplemyserver.com/'+"ZoomDict['{z}']"+'/{x}/{y}.jpg').addto(map)//out :put URL for tiles is :  http://www.examplemyserver.com/undefind/45/245.jpg'
or
mp=L.tileLayer('http://www.examplemyserver.com/{ZoomDict['{z}']}/{x}/{y}.jpg').addto(map) //out put: URL for tiles is :  http://www.examplemyserver.com/{ZoomDict['{7}']}/45/245.jpg'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the Leaflet Tile Layer URL template will just perform string replacement, which leads to the results you report.

In your case you want to customize the zoom value used to build the tiles URL. To do so, you can override the [`getTileUrl`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#tilelayer-gettileurl) method of Tile Layer class:

```js
const TileLayerCustom = L.TileLayer.extend({
  getTileUrl(coords) {
    return `http://www.examplemyserver.com/${ZoomDict[coords.z]}/${coords.x}/${coords.y}.jpg`;
  }
});

const mp = new TileLayerCustom().addTo(map);
```